# How to close mongoose connection after forEach executes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code where I open a new mongoose connection to insert records, however when I try to close the connection after the forEach (which is supposed to be blocking) then it executes the mongoose.connection.close() inmediatly and doesn't insert any records on the database. Any ideas of how to do this?

Here is my code

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
const Model = require('./model');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/exel', (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
});

let obj = xlsx.parse(file);
obj[0].data.forEach((item, index) => {
    let newItem = {
        nombre: item[2],
        localidad: item[7],
        cargo: item[8]
    }

    Model.create(newItem)
    .then((createdItem) => {
        console.log(createdItem);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

mongoose.connection.close();
```

I tried creating a function with the forEach code inside it and adding the mongoose.connection.close() as a callback, using promises, using async and a few others but nothing works.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how node works asynchronously. The `forEach` is blocking, as you state, however, what happens is you loop over everything and call `Model.create` which returns immediately (it's waiting for it's callback to be fired). This means that `mongoose.connection.close` will execute almost instantly. Try looking at async for an asynchronous for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this.

For example:

```
async = require("async");
async.each(items, function(item, callback){
    // Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
    item.someAsyncCall(function (){
      // Async call is done, alert via callback
      callback();
    });
  },
  // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
  function(err){
    // All tasks are done now
    doSomethingOnceAllAreDone();
  }
);
```